# Qt5のレイアウト設定について

Tags: qt5

Qt5について、下のようにすると、ボタンなどが全く表示されず、空のボックスが表示されます。コンパイルが通っているのでエラー？なのかどうかよくわかりませんが、コンソールに

QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on MainWindow "", which already has a layout

と表示されます。setLayoutの使い方が間違っている気がするのですが、わかる方助けてください。

```
//Header
#include <QMainWindow>
#include<QVBoxLayout>
#include<QLabel>
#include<QPushButton>
#include<QHBoxLayout>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();
private:
};
//mainファイル
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

return a.exec();
}


 //cpp_file
#include "mainwindow.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QVBoxLayout *vLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    vLayout->addWidget(new QLabel("hello"));
    vLayout->addWidget(new QPushButton("hello2"));
    QHBoxLayout *hLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    hLayout->addLayout(vLayout);
    hLayout->addWidget(new QPushButton("hello3"));

    setLayout(hLayout);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}
```

Comment: 最終的にLayoutではなく、Widgetに積み込めばよいのですね！ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず、全体を格納するためのウィジェット（CentralWidget）を作成してください。

ラベルやボタン等を作成する際は、親ウィジェットとして、自分自身のMainWindow（`this`）を指定してください。

すべてのパーツを作成し終わったら、`setCentralWidget`を行ってください。

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QWidget *central = new QWidget(this);

    QVBoxLayout *vLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    vLayout->addWidget(new QLabel("hello", this));
    vLayout->addWidget(new QPushButton("hello2", this));
    QHBoxLayout *hLayout = new QHBoxLayout(central);
    hLayout->addLayout(vLayout);
    hLayout->addWidget(new QPushButton("hello3", this));

    setCentralWidget(central);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

soramimiさんの回答とは別の回答です。

質問のコードで、`MainWindow`を`QMainWindow`の派生クラスとしていますが、`QWidget`の派生クラスにすると期待通り動作すると思います。

```
    // コード例 (mainwindow.h)
    #include <QWidget>

    class MainWindow : public QWidget {
        /* 省略 */
    };
```

補足です。`QMainWindow`はメニューバー、ステータスバー、CentralWidget等、一般的なウインドウが持つパーツを配置しやすいような仕様になっており、最初からLayoutを持っているので件のメッセージが表示されるようです。
具体的な仕様は、[`QMainWindow`のヘルプ](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html)を参照してみてください。
ちなみに、その説明には、次のように「CentralWidgetは設定する必要がある」とあります。

> Creating a main window without a central widget is not supported. You must have a central widget even if it is just a placeholder.